# How to groupby and aggregate on the same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have a sales dataframe

```
Date    Store   Company     product             Amount
1-1-18  A       company_x       A001               10
1-1-18  A       company_y       A002               20
1-1-18  A       comapny_z       A003               30
1-1-18  B       comapny_x       A001               40
1-1-18  B       company_y       A002               50
1-1-18  B       company_z       A003               60
2-1-18  A       company_x       A001               10
2-1-18  A       company_y       A002               20
2-1-18  A       comapny_z       A003               30
2-1-18  B       comapny_x       A001               40
2-1-18  B       company_y       A002               50
2-1-18  B       company_z       A003               60
2-1-18  A       company_x       A001               10
2-1-18  A       company_y       A002               20
2-1-18  A       comapny_z       A003               30
2-1-18  B       comapny_x       A001               40
2-1-18  B       company_y       A002               50
2-1-18  B       company_z       A003               60
2-1-18  A       company_x       A001               10
2-1-18  A       company_y       A002               20
2-1-18  A       comapny_z       A003               30
2-1-18  B       comapny_x       A001               40
2-1-18  B       company_y       A002               50
2-1-18  B       company_z       A003               60
3-1-18  A       company_x       A001               10
3-1-18  A       company_y       A002               20
3-1-18  A       comapny_z       A003               30
3-1-18  B       comapny_x       A001               40
3-1-18  B       company_y       A002               50
3-1-18  B       company_z       A003               60
```

I want to get the unique count of sales order of each product grouping by product, Company and Store

```
Store   Company     product          Count
A       Company_x       A001            5 
B       Company_y       A002            5
C       Company_z       A003            5
```

I tried

```
df.groupby(['Store','Company','Product'],as_index='False').agg({'product':'nunique'})
```

But python throws me an value error, apparently I cant use same column for grouping and aggregating it seems.

I will appreciate your kind help to achieve my goal

Edit :

I appreciate all your answers to help me, but it was my bad. Actually I want to find the unique number of Days these products have been sold.

So the solution is ,    df.groupby(['Store','Company','Product'],as_index='False').agg({'Date':'nunique'})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregating with `nunique` on the index `product` would return `1` for each group as `product` is the last level in the index.

Use the aggregate function `'size'` and rename the series to `count` as in your example. Then `reset_index` or alternatively groupby with option `as_index=False`.

```
df.groupby(['Store', 'Company', 'product']).agg('size').rename('count').reset_index()

  Store    Company product  count
0     A  comapny_z    A003      5
1     A  company_x    A001      5
2     A  company_y    A002      5
3     B  comapny_x    A001      5
4     B  company_y    A002      5
5     B  company_z    A003      5
```

Comment: Thanks Ali for your help. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be 2 issues:

1. Your series name is `product`, not `Product`.
2. To get a count of the number of items, you can use `len`. `nunique` gives number of unique values.

Here's a demo:

```
res = df.groupby(['Store','Company','product'],as_index='False').agg({'product': len})

print(res)
                         product
Store Company   product         
A     comapny_z A003           5
      company_x A001           5
      company_y A002           5
B     comapny_x A001           5
      company_y A002           5
      company_z A003           5
```

Comment: Hi @jpp, did you just run the code , I ran the same piece of code , I get this error ValueError: cannot insert product, already exists. the product error which you mentioned was a typo

Comment: @AhamedMoosa, Unfortunately, I can't replicate your error. You can try editting your question with the output of `df.head().to_dict()` so we have a complete example.

Comment: Hi @jpp, thanks for pointing out, it was my mistake, I want to know the unique number of days it has been sold. I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

`count` on groupby will return all the count for unique row and then selecting amount and renaming the column will do the job.

```
data.groupby(['Store','Company','product'],as_index='False').count()['Amount'].rename('count').reset_index()

  Store    Company product  count
0     A  comapny_z    A003      5
1     A  company_x    A001      5
2     A  company_y    A002      5
3     B  comapny_x    A001      5
4     B  company_y    A002      5
5     B  company_z    A003      5
```